# pycharm debugger not connecting: KeyboardInterrupt

Tags: python, debugging, connection, pycharm

Somehow my `pycharm` debugger **doesn't connect anymore**.

I tested all ENV. Also, reading up on it on stackoverflow: I deleted the **.idea directory**.

However, after restarting the pycharm .idea is always **recreated** (deleted caches and even deleted&downlaoded pycharm again)

```
**/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/bin/python3.6 "/Applications/PyCharm CE.app/Contents/helpers/pydev/pydevd.py" --multiproc --qt-support --client 127.0.0.1 --port 52281 --file /Users/franzi/Desktop/i18n/qordoba-cli/qordoba/cli.py i18n-find --traceback
warning: Debugger speedups using cython not found. Run '"/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/bin/python3.6" "/Applications/PyCharm CE.app/Contents/helpers/pydev/setup_cython.py" build_ext --inplace' to build.
pydev debugger: process 96448 is connecting

Connected to pydev debugger (build 171.4694.67)
Could not connect to 127.0.0.1: 52282
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Applications/PyCharm CE.app/Contents/helpers/pydev/pydevd.py", line 1583, in <module>
    debugger.connect(host, port)
  File "/Applications/PyCharm CE.app/Contents/helpers/pydev/pydevd.py", line 324, in connect
    self.initialize_network(s)
  File "/Applications/PyCharm CE.app/Contents/helpers/pydev/pydevd.py", line 316, in initialize_network
    time.sleep(0.1)  # give threads time to start
KeyboardInterrupt

Process finished with exit code 1**
```

Comment: Can you describe how you are starting the debugger (sounds like a `remote debugger`) and what happened to cause it to stop working?

Comment: just by pushing debugging botton on the top right corner. It stopped by itself..

Comment: When you click that button, it's running a run configuration. Something may have gotten fubar'd with yours, so you should create a new one. `Run | Debug ...` -> Edit configurations -> `+` -> `Python` -> Create new configuration -> Run new configuration

Answer (score 16):

I had similar problem. I have removed (remove, not disable) all existing breakpoints (in the dialog box invoked by <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>F8</kbd>). After removing all breakpoints and modifying run configuration (disable add content roots and add source roots to PYTHONPATH) debugging started to work. Enabling them back and still working fine - problem gone.

I think that removing breakpoints will be sufficient to solve the issue. See hint from JetBrains community:
https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/115000014004/comments/115000239630

Comment: did not work for me :(